# Euclidean volume of symmetric matrices in operator norm

Tags: matrices, convex-geometry, matrix-analysis

This is a nearly identical question to [Euclidean volume of the unit ball of matrices under the matrix norm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1464/euclidean-volume-of-the-unit-ball-of-matrices-under-the-matrix-norm) except in the symmetric case.

Let $\mathrm{Sym}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of real-valued $n \times n$ symmetric matrices. Let $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2} \mapsto \mathrm{Sym}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ embed $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$ into $\mathrm{Sym}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$. 
Consider the set $H_n = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2} : \| \phi(v) \| \leq 1 \}$, where $\|M\| = \max_{\|x\|=1} \|Mx\|$ is the $\ell_2 \mapsto \ell_2$ operator norm.

What is the formula for $\mathrm{Vol}(H_n)$, where $\mathrm{Vol}(\cdot)$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzeved that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out